# Corona/Lua Runtime Error

Tags: lua, runtime, coronasdk, simulator

So recently I was adding "Tune" analytics to my app and when I tested on Corona Simulator everything worked just fine.
 But when I made apk build to android, I launched app and just on launch I got this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u27hN.jpg
Can someone please help? I think that some problem is in build.settings

Whole "Tune" documentation:
https://developers.tune.com/sdk/corona-plugin-quick-start/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this

- Activate Tune plugin in [marketplace](https://marketplace.coronalabs.com/plugin/tune)
- Post [Analytics Plugins - which to choose for now?](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/67060-analytics-plugins-which-to-choose-for-now/?hl=tune) suggest use of [Google Analytics](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2016/02/15/announcing-the-google-analytics-plugin/) plugin (Tune plugin is incompatible with [GPGS](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2016/09/02/our-new-google-play-games-services-gpgs-plugin-is-available/) plugin)

Comment: Looks like GPGS was problem, thank you for solving it